# Updating git repo after using git-filter-repo --subdirectory-filter

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

I have extracted a tools folder to it's own repo using:
`git-filter-repo --subdirectory-filter path/to/tools`

In parallel, new commits are being made in the original repo.

I would like to be able to periodically merge the changes into my filtered repo.
The only thing I can think is to clone the original repo again (with the changes), apply the subdirectory-filter on it again, add it as a remote to my repo, then cherry-pick/merge the branch from there. It is a lot to perform every time there is a small change. I think there's probably a smart way to create a filtered patch from the main repo and then apply it to the filtered, but my git-skills are not sufficient.

Can someone come up with a better way to do it?

Comment: I think the "subtree merge" discussed here might be suitable: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#_subtree_merge There also is (or was?) a "git subtree" command, but it doesn't seem to be listed in the online manual (was it removed?)

Comment: Hm, manual page is still in the git repo; just missing from the website, I guess... https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt

Comment: @IMSoP It's a contrib package, currently poorly maintained, so *caveat emptor*...

Comment: @torek Ah, that makes sense. I remembered using it for something years ago, and was surprised at how hard it was to find the documentation. It looks like [it's had at least some fixes recently](https://github.com/git/git/commits/master/contrib/subtree) so might be worth the OP looking into.

Comment: @amirblum : can you try re-running `git filter-repo ...` on the same original history, and check the `sha` of the generated commits ? if it keeps as is the data associated to each commit (author name, author date, committer name, committer date) it should recreate the exact same commits on each run.

Comment: @LeGEC : Ran it. It does remap the hashes the same on the shared history, so that is good. It's still a lot of work to re-filter and re-add it as a remote every time though...

Comment: At this point I'm just complaining though. For my use case, re-filtering and merging is good enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `git filter-repo` will recreate the *exact same commits* if you run it twice on the exact same history (you confirmed it by testing), you can simply use `git merge` to integrate the new commits, which will appear as descendants of the previous extracted commit.

Comment: You saved me hours of testing weird strategies. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim +1 . The only caveat is: you have to use the exact same command in all future updates.

Comment: I did it yesterday, and rebased/ff onto the existing branch, and the history looks beautiful.